# How to exit Databricks Notebook if no data is present in a table or view?

Tags: databricks, azure-databricks, databricks-sql

I would like a Databricks notebook to exit or stop execution if a query on table returns with no data.

For example, if I execute the following code:

```
df = sql("select * from TableA")
```

And there is no data in TableA then "Stop Execution".

I read somewhere something like this might work

```
if (df.TableA[0]==0): dbutils.notebook.exit('stop')
```

But I don't think the above will tell me if the table is empty

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
df = spark.sql("select * from TableA")
if(df.count() == 0):
  dbutils.notebook.exit('stop')
```